# Binary XML file line Error inflating class Button in drawable

Tags: android

what should i add instead of this button code?

**Mainactivity**

```
  package com.example.sharma.ubernew;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

**Logcat**
APP is not starting .stopped.

```
07-31 19:26:52.919 11371-11371/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.sharma.ubernew, PID: 11371
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.sharma.ubernew/com.example.sharma.ubernew.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #69: Error inflating class Button
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2195)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #69: Error inflating class Button
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:713)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139)
    at com.example.sharma.ubernew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5397)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File res/drawable/btn_register_background.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f07005c
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2131)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694)
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:629)
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:70)
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:186)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.sharma.ubernew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5397) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
 Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #2: invalid drawable tag ripple
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXmlInner(Drawable.java:933)
    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromXml(Drawable.java:877)
    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2127)
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602) 
    at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3694) 
    at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:629) 
    at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:107) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:70) 
    at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:66) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:186) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:109) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1035) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1092) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:684) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:287) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:139) 
    at com.example.sharma.ubernew.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:11) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5397) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1113) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2159) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2245) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5021) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:827) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:643) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    <TextView
        android:text="U B E R"
        android:textSize="36sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <TextView
        android:text="PARTNER"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txt_rider_app"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="LOOKING FOR THE RIDER APP"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

<LinearLayout
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_above="@id/txt_rider_app"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:background="@color/btnSignIn"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:text="SIGN IN"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnRegister"
        android:background="@drawable/btn_register_background"
        android:textColor="@color/btnRegister"
        android:text="REGISTER"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

the error is in drawable sign in xml file
**btn_sign_in_background**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/rippleEffectColor"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/btnSignIn"/>
            <stroke android:color="@color/btnSignIn" android:width="2dp">
            </stroke>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>

        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

**btn_register_background**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:color="@color/rippleEffectColor"
    tools:targetApi="lollipop">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>
            <stroke android:color="@android:color/white" android:width="2dp">
            </stroke>
            <corners android:radius="2dp"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
</ripple>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using @color/btnSignIn. Change this to `@drawable/btn_sign_in_background` in `android:background` property as done in:-

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
    android:background="@drawable/btn_sign_in_background"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="SIGN IN"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

I got  this same error while running my application.
In my case actually problem is that   custom_button.xml drawable file present in drawable-v21 folder not in drawable folder, which causes the error, I removed it by copying it into on drawable folder
I think in your case btn_register_background.xml file present In something folder like drawable-v21 or drawable-v24 or anything like that, try copy btn_register_background.xml into drawable folder.